# How to get HttpStatusCode.NoContent message passing throw Web API in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-ajax

**Web Api Code**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();
            TestDBContext dbconntext = new TestDBContext();
            var allKey = ControllerContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
            var customerCode = allKey.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "CustomerCode").Value;
            var customerName = allKey.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "CustomerName").Value;


            customerList = dbconntext.Customers.
                    Where(x => x.CustomerName.Contains((customerName == null) || (customerName == "") ? x.CustomerName : customerName)
                    && x.CustomerCode.Contains((customerCode == null) || (customerCode == "") ? x.CustomerCode : customerCode))
                    .ToList<Customer>();

            if (customerList != null && customerList.Count > 0)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customerList);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, string.Format(" No customer is found with supplies values as Customer Code:{0} and Customer Name :{1}",customerCode,customerName));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
      //  return customerList;
    }
```

**Java Script Code**

```
$scope.Search = function () {

        $http({
            url: "api/customerapi?CustomerCode="+$scope.Customer.CustomerCode+"&&CustomerName="+$scope.Customer.CustomerName,
            method: "get",
            //params: { CustomerName: $scope.SearchCustomerName },
        }).then(function (response) {
               $scope.customers = response.data;
        },
            function (response) {
               alert(response.data);
            });
    }
```

**No how to get custom message passes from WebApi when HttpStatusCode.NoContent return** 
I am receiving only status
status:204 & statusText:"No Content"
so how can we get custom message from webAPI

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, string.Format(" No customer is found with supplies values as Customer Code:{0} and Customer Name :{1}",customerCode,customerName)
```

Comment: If you are using `No Content (204)` then it indicates that response is blank. Either you need to return `204` and then handle the error message in Javascript as you should have customer name and customer code in JS. Another solution is to change the status code to `200` and then return the content.

Comment: If you use Postman you get that message?

Comment: Hello. It is not recommended to use NoContent Status Code with content.
Please read here [HttpStatusCode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx). You could use `HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError` for catch and `HttpStatusCode.BadRequest` instead of `HttpStatusCode.NoContent`. Now except that use `console.log(response)` to find where your content value is. But first make sure that it gets on the response as Martin says: Use the postman or the network profile of your browser's dev tools.